# executing the wrong function in if statement

Tags: javascript

```js
/* 
GAME FUNCTION:

- player must guess a number beetween min and max
- player gets a certain amount of guesses
- notify player of guesses remaining
- notify the player with a correct number if he loose
- let player choose to play again
*/


// variabels

//game values
let min = 1,
max = 10,
winningNum = 2,
guessesLeft = 3;

// UI elements
const game = document.getElementById('game'),
minNum = document.querySelector('.min-num'),
maxNum = document.querySelector('.max-num'),
guessBtn = document.getElementById('guess-btn'),  
guessInput = document.getElementById('guess-input'),  
message = document.querySelector('.message');

// assign ui min and max
minNum.textContent = min;
maxNum.textContent = max;

// event listener

function loadEventListener() {
    // listen for guess
    guessBtn.addEventListener('click' , checkGuess );
    
};

loadEventListener();

// checks the entered number
function checkGuess() {
    let guess = parseInt(guessInput.value);
    
    //validate the input
    if(isNaN(guess) || guess < min || guess > max ) {
        console.log('here')
/////// this below code setMessage is not executing when the condintions are true.. ////
        setMessage(`Please enter a number between ${min} and ${max}` , 'red');
        console.log('here again')
        
    };
    
    //check if won
    if(guess === winningNum) {
        // right case here
        //dsiabe input
        guessInput.disabled = true;
        // change border color
        guessInput.style.borderColor = 'green';
        // set message
        setMessage(`${winningNum} is correct.. you WON the game!!` , 'green');
    } else {
        // wrong case here
        guessesLeft -= 1;
        
        if(guessesLeft === 0) {
            // game over - lost
            // disable input
            guessInput.disabled = true;
            // change border color
            guessInput.style.borderColor = 'red';
            // set message
            setMessage(`Game over..! The correct Number was ${winningNum}..` , 'red');
        } else {
            // game continues - answer wrong
            // change border color
            guessInput.style.borderColor = 'red';
            // clear input
            guessInput.value = '';
            // tell user its the number 
            setMessage(`${guess} is not Correct,${guessesLeft} guesses left.` , 'orange')
             };
        
    }
};


// set message
function setMessage(msg , color) {
    message.style.color = color;
    message.textContent = msg;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/skeleton/2.0.4/skeleton.css" />
    <title>Number Guesser</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <h1>Number Guesser</h1>
        <div id="game">
            <p>Guess a number beetween 
                <span class="min-num"></span>
                and 
                <span class="max-num"></span>
            </p>
            <input type="number" name="" id="guess-input" placeholder="Enter Your Guess...">
            <input type="submit" value="submit" id="guess-btn">
            <p class="message"></p>
        </div>
    </div>
    
    <script src="app.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

when i click on the submit button without entering the values, the function in line 49 **setMessage** should execute, but its executing the code of 82nd line.., it should display the message (message placed in the argument) in 49th line code but its showing message from 82nd line.. please look at the issue..what else is wrong in the code???

Comment: I hope you do not expect us to count your lines...

Comment: In those declarations under `//UI elements`, are they meant to be *all* constants, or one constant and variables. Here it's useful adding keywords so the interpreter and humans don't get confused.

Comment: @Justinas Yes, you should label your lines, maybe showing us with comments which ones aren't working

Comment: sorry i thought it will show the numbers of each line.. ill change it now

Comment: Add `return;` after you set the error message.  As it stands it fails validation, shows an error message and then carries on processing.  You need to stop it before it goes any further (or wrap the rest of the code in an `else` block).

Comment: please have a look at it.. i mentioned it in comment.. issue is at after the eventlistener and checkGuess function @JBDouble05

Comment: thank you so much @Archer it worked..

Comment: @Archer mind making this an answer?

Comment: I'm a bit reluctant as it was such a small mistake, or oversight.

Comment: i̶f̶ ̶i̶s̶ ̶n̶o̶t̶ ̶a̶ ̶l̶o̶o̶p̶. EDIT: Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is that you don't exit the `checkGuess()` function when it fails validation.

If you add a `return;` after the failed validation error is shown then it will solve your issue...

```
function checkGuess() {
    let guess = parseInt(guessInput.value);

    //validate the input
    if(isNaN(guess) || guess < min || guess > max ) {
        setMessage(`Please enter a number between ${min} and ${max}` , 'red');

        return; // exit the function here, since we've failed validation
    };
```

Comment: No problem - happy to help :)